# Flutter: How To Change/Refresh State From Another Widget

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have a global integer that is displayed in a widget and then is updated by something (a button click or something) from another widget. All of the other ways i have tried don't work. What is the best way to do this?

Stack overflow says i have too much code so more text more text more text

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ScoreDisplay(),
              PointButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

int score = 0;

class ScoreDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScoreDisplayState createState() => _ScoreDisplayState();
}

class _ScoreDisplayState extends State<ScoreDisplay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          'Score: $score',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PointButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: RaisedButton(
          //onPressed: //increment score,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement some kind of State Management for that.

[image]

Here are two basic ways to implement such a feature: with a **StatefulWidget** and with **Riverpod**.

### 1. With a StatefulWidget

I extracted your Scaffold as a `StatefulWidget` maintaining the `score` of your application.

I then use `ScoreDisplay` as a pure `StatelessWidget` receiving the `score` as a parameter. And your `PointButton` is also Stateless and call the `ScorePage` thanks to a simple `VoidCallback` function.

### Full source code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: ScorePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class ScorePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScorePage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScorePageState createState() => _ScorePageState();
}

class _ScorePageState extends State<ScorePage> {
  int score = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            ScoreDisplay(score: score),
            PointButton(onIncrement: () => setState(() => score++)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScoreDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final int score;

  const ScoreDisplay({Key key, this.score}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          'Score: $score',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PointButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onIncrement;

  const PointButton({Key key, this.onIncrement}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => onIncrement?.call(),
          child: Text('CLICK ME'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### 2. With Riverpod

Create a `StateProvider`:

```dart
final scoreProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);
```

Watch the `StateProvider`:

```dart
final score = useProvider(scoreProvider).state;
```

Update the StateProvider

```dart
context.read(scoreProvider).state++
```

#### Full Source Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                ScoreDisplay(),
                PointButton(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

int score = 0;

class ScoreDisplay extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final score = useProvider(scoreProvider).state;
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          'Score: $score',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PointButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => context.read(scoreProvider).state++,
          child: Text('CLICK ME'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final scoreProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);
```

Check [Riverpod Website](https://riverpod.dev) for more info and more advanced use cases.

But you have [many more flavors of State Management available](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Answer (score 1):

The best example is to use "provider" package which can be found on [www.pub.dev](http://www.pub.dev)
It is very easy state management package that can help You solve this problem. Keep in my that provider instead of setState() uses notifyListener()